# Как задать координаты imageView в место куда юзер кликнул на photoView

Tags: java, android

Я использую [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) для того чтобы картинка была увеличиваемой. Когда юзер кликает на нее, срабатывает `onPhotoTap` (я использую `onPhotoTap` чтобы прослеживать куда юзер кликнул именно в `drawable`). Мне нужно чтобы когда юзер кликал на определенную часть этой картинки, прямо на этом же месте (в тех же координатах где кликнул юзер) появлялась еще одна картинка (`imageView`), своего рода `bubble text` (поверх картинки в `photoView`), но я не знаю как задать координаты для нее. За любую помощь спасибо заранее

Comment: можно поместить все в контейнер FrameLayout а отступать посредством задания margin - я так делал у себя в проекте

Comment: @Style-7 можно поподробнее по поводу отступать посредством задания margin? Я новичок, сори )

Answer (score 0):

Используйте FrameLayout для того чтобы отображать элементы поверх друг друга.

Вот например код для помещения textview поверх imageview:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/bitmapie" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/descTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="TextView placed at the top of the Imageview"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Для того чтобы установить координаты этого textview можно использовать margin-это внешние отступы. В активити их можно установить вот так:

You should use LayoutParams to set your button margins:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
yourbutton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

left,right,top,bottom это отступы которые вам нужно изменять в зависимости от координат.